# Custom font garbled rendering on Samsung Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, fonts, samsung-mobile

We're using a custom ttf font (Calibri) for an app and it renders really badly on Samsung 4.4.2, in some cases no text is rendered at all. On other tested devices and Samsung with other versions (4.4.4, 4.1.2), there are no issues at all. For two Samsung devices (the only two we have with 4.4.2) it looks like this:

[image: garbled font rendering]

We are using the MagicViews library (https://github.com/ikocijan/MagicViews) to deal with custom fonts, so far we didn't have any problems with it.

EDIT:
This also happens when loading the font manually, without the library.

Comment: I don't see an issue about this filed by you on the MagicViews issue tracker, which is most definitely the place to go *before* asking on Stackoverflow. Can you file this question with them so that the people most qualified to comment on it can do so?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans good point. We tried displaying the font without using the library and we got the same result, so it's not something the library does.

Comment: I know Android 4.2 and 4.3 had super bad code for working with webfonts, which supposedly got fixed in in 4.4, but it *might* have only properly been fixed in 4.4.4 - http://caniuse.com isn't specific enough about that, so finding that information might require trawling the Android bug tracker.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks, that's a solid clue. :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.. we solved this by using an `.otf` version of the font instead of `.ttf`. My guess is Calibri uses some feature of the ttf format which doesn't work well in this case.